# React map using Objects.entries for rendering inputs dynamically and change values of individual fields

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically render over 100 inputs with preset values using react hooks these values will need to be editable.

I need to map out the inputs using both keys and values.

Currently my code renders all inputs and I can change the values of each individual input, but when I update the value of one input the value of all keys get changed.

below is my code

```
import React from 'react'

export default function test() {
 const [exampleState, setExampleState]  = React.useState([{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}]);

const handleChange1 = (e, id) => {
  
  var result = Object.entries(exampleState);
  result = result.map(([key, subject], i)=>{
  if (key === id) subject = e.target.value 
  key = id
  return [key, subject];
  })
 
  setExampleState(result)
  }
  return (
    <div>
         <form>
      {Object.entries(exampleState).map(([key, subject], i) => {
        return (
         
      <label key={i}>{key} 
         <br/>
          <input 
          key={i}
          type="text"  
          id= {key}
        value={subject}  
        onChange={(e) => handleChange1(e, key)} />
       </label>
        );
      })}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

on change the value of exampleState changes to something like this

```
{
 "0": "value1",
    "1": "value2",
    "2": "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your state should be an object not an array.(I think you missed it when you were typing the question)

So replace this:

```js
const [exampleState, setExampleState]  = useState([{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}]);
```

With this:

```js
const [exampleState, setExampleState]  = useState({
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
});
```

2. Simply update your value of the selected key instead of looping through all entries.

So hope it helps:

```js
export function Test() {
  const [exampleState, setExampleState]  = useState({
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  });

  const handleChange = (event, key) => {
    const newExampleState = {...exampleState};
    newExampleState[key] = event.target.value;
    setExampleState(newExampleState);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(exampleState);
  }, [exampleState])

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {
          Object.entries(exampleState).map(([key, subject], i) => {
            return (
              <label key={i}>{key} 
                <br/>
                <input key={i} type="text" id= {key} value={subject} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, key)} />
              </label>
            );
          })
        }
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```